# How do I access a certain string variable in a json API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am using the weatherunderground api, and I would like to access the forecast only for today. I usually use parsed_json[][] until I get the variable I need, but in this case there is an array. Here is my code:

```
function findWeather() {



  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $.ajax({
  url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/c531e176f43b999d/forecast/q/CT/Old_Greenwich.json",
  dataType : "jsonp",
  success : function(parsed_json) {

  var forecasts = parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday: 0']['fcttext'];

   var forecastString = "The weather is" + forecasts + "."
   speak(" test" + forecastString);
  }
  });
});  
}
function speak(x) {
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(x);
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}
```

If you go to the URL, you will see the entire sheet and the info I am trying to access. I've been trying to solve this for a few hours, and can't find any help with google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`parsed_json['forecast']['txt_forecast']['forecastday'][0]['fcttext'];`

Don't know what you expect the :0 to do, but it won't de-reference the array.